# Why does `onResponse` never gets invoked?

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit, okhttp

I am making a post request with an audio file uploaded with a multipart/form-data in Android Studio and it successfully gives me a 200 response but I am unable to print the response. It gives a strange output coming from OkHttp.

OkHTpp output:

```
    I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST https://zenya-image-class.herokuapp.com/getText
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=169ee4dc-0587-4a82-85a7-fe5af0c3a5e9
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 753233
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --169ee4dc-0587-4a82-85a7-fe5af0c3a5e9
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="AudioRecording.wav"
    Content-Type: audio/*
    Content-Length: 753024
    RIFFx}��WAVEfmt ����������D������������dataT}���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������� 
    // IT IS LONGER THAN THIS BUT IT IS THE SAME CHARACTERS TILL THE END
```

Here is my post request:

```
    File file = new File(filename);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/*"), file);
   
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);

    speechApi.postWavAudio(body)
            .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse response:: " + response);


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure error:: " + t);
                }
            });
```

It never reaches the onResponse part although it returns me a 200 Success. Also, it does work in Postman.

Comment: Is your question about the “weird characters” or the fact that `onResponse` is never invoked?  (The “weird characters” are normal and expected;  audio data is not readable text.)

Comment: @VGR It would be why the onResponse is never invoked.

Comment: @AngelHadzhiev What do you mean it never reaches `onResponse` part although it returns you a 200 success? HTTP response code can only be checked inside `onResponse` callback. if you want to check what was sent from the server you need to check `response.body()`.

Comment: @YaMiN it never prints response.body()

Comment: @AngelHadzhiev Then maybe no response body is sent from the server.